# Is there anyway to reset multi index in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to obtain stock data using pandas_datareader. I have the data, but the index I got is `multiIndex.
_data.columns`

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close', 'Volume', 'Adj Close'], ['MSFT']],
           codes=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
           names=['Attributes', 'Symbols'])




from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import yfinance
_data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(['MSFT'], start='2019-01-01', end='2019-05-30')
```

The format I want to get is single index.So that i can use that data to plot

```
    symbol  date            price
0   MSFT    2000-01-01  39.81
1   MSFT    2000-02-01  36.35
2   MSFT    2000-03-01  43.22
3   MSFT    2000-04-01  28.37
4   MSFT    2000-05-01  25.45
```

Comment: Can you share what have you tried?

Comment: have you tried `_data.reset_index()`

Comment: Hi @harvpan .I have tried _data.reset_index(), but it is not working as i desire

Comment: Yes @Datanovice , i tried that too

Comment: can you show the sample input?

Comment: Try pass the level you want to reset: `data.reset_index(level=[1,2,3])`?

Comment: maybe try `df['Close'].unstack(level=1).reset_index(name='Price')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several "Price" Columns to choose from.  I chose `'Adj Close'`.  This is mostly the same as [ChrisA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56381714/is-there-anyway-to-reset-multi-index-in-pandas/56382230#comment99364733_56381714)'s comment.

```
_data.stack()['Adj Close'].reset_index(name='Price')

          Date Symbols       Price
0   2019-01-02    MSFT  100.318642
1   2019-01-03    MSFT   96.628120
2   2019-01-04    MSFT  101.122223
3   2019-01-07    MSFT  101.251190
4   2019-01-08    MSFT  101.985329
..         ...     ...         ...
```

Comment: Hi @piRSquared ..Thanks for your help..I am not able exactly understand the code part..but this works for me...is that possible for you to provide all price columns at once

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `reset_index` with `melt`

```
 from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import yfinance
_data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(['MSFT'], start='2019-01-01', end='2019-05-30')
print(_data)


   Attributes   High    Low Open    Close   Volume  Adj Close
Symbols MSFT    MSFT    MSFT    MSFT    MSFT    MSFT
Date                        
2019-01-02  101.750000  98.940002   99.550003   101.120003  35329300.0  100.318642
2019-01-03  100.190002  97.199997   100.099998  97.400002   42523600.0  96.628120
2019-01-04  102.510002  98.930000   99.720001   101.930000  44060600.0  101.122223
2019-01-07  103.269997  100.980003  101.639999  102.059998  35656100.0  101.251190
2019-01-08  103.970001  101.709999  103.040001  102.800003  31514400.0  101.985329
```

we can `reset_index` and `melt` passing `date` as our `id_vars`

```
df = _data.reset_index().melt(id_vars='Date') # You can filter out attributes if you don't need them.
print(df)


 Date   Attributes  Symbols value
0   2019-01-02  High    MSFT    101.750000
1   2019-01-03  High    MSFT    100.190002
2   2019-01-04  High    MSFT    102.510002
3   2019-01-07  High    MSFT    103.269997
4   2019-01-08  High    MSFT    103.970001
5   2019-01-09  High    MSFT    104.879997
6   2019-01-10  High    MSFT    103.750000
7   2019-01-11  High    MSFT    103.440002
```

Comment: ...what needs to be done if I want to get all the columns and values

Comment: Sorry I don't understand

Comment: I mean i want all the columns of the data [High, Low ,Open, Close   Volume , Adj Close]

Comment: @Deepak probably not very elegant, but you could try `_data.T.unstack().T.reset_index()` I think piRSquared answer is much better tho, use that one :)

Comment: Thanks @Datanovice ..really appreciate for all your help

Comment: @Deepak no problem bhai! P.S up votes are a good way to say thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution to your problem might be:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
data = pdr.get_data_yahoo(['MSFT'], start='2019-01-01', end='2019-05-30')
data.columns = data.columns.levels[0]
data['symbol'] = 'MSFT'
data.head()

Attributes  High    Low Open    Close   Volume  Adj Close   symbol
Date                            
2019-01-02  101.750000  98.940002   99.550003   101.120003  35329300.0  100.318642  MSFT
2019-01-03  100.190002  97.199997   100.099998  97.400002   42523600.0  96.628120   MSFT
2019-01-04  102.510002  98.930000   99.720001   101.930000  44060600.0  101.122223  MSFT
2019-01-07  103.269997  100.980003  101.639999  102.059998  35656100.0  101.251190  MSFT
2019-01-08  103.970001  101.709999  103.040001  102.800003  31514400.0  101.985329  MSFT
```

Comment: I like your answer..but i want to plot using altair..thanks anyway...It is helpful as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to use multiindex droplevel
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html